# Collect data from 80 users, hiding other user's data

Tags: database, forms, ms-office

My wife works for a medium sized retail chain.  Managers from each of the 80 outlets have to fill in one row of performance info for each of their staff (900 in all), but aren't allowed to see the data of other stores' staff.

My wife currently manages this with lots of spreadsheets, because each month the executive change what they want to collect, and their IT team don't have the resources to update their SAS system.  She has to manually compile all the data into 1 spreadsheet for analysis which is time consuming and error prone. She's recently gone from having to do this for 20 outlets to 80 outlets and thinks she must be an easier way.

Is there a simple form based system, that can leverage what is already installed (microsoft office and lotus but not MSAccess), or can be run from a network drive.  Cloud apps are banned.    Excel's security is all wrong.  Can word form templates append to a shared data source?  Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Send out an identical Excel template to each manager, then use programming code to combine them into one worksheet. You can place all the files into a folder and write a loop that parses each file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single table with all the data, then create 'shadowtables' on this table for each individual store.

in MySQL this would probably be either a 'partition table' (I've never used this so not sure how it works) or the use of temp tables.

You would then need to implement a method whereby when a user logs in at a given location (IP address) a trigger would create the temp table, then populate it with the relevent data for the store at that IP address.

An alternative (probably easier too) would be to have a specied table for each store, then grant users specific priveleges on each table you create. Again you'll need trigers to either populate a single 'master table' with info as it is updated, or you will just send a
    select * from outlet1, outlet2... outlet80

again you may decide to create a temp table from the above select, and implement a custom script to create it only when required.
In fact that is probably how I would do it.
Then in you web interface have a button to create the temp table, and display it to the current user (provided they have the required priveleges to view all the tables of course).

I don't know for certain if Lotus is able to implement this, I don't know about its 'database' solution. I know that to do something similar in Access isn't that hard, the only downside would be needing to handle user identification (which Access doesn't do natively), again I don't know about Lotus.

In my experience the 'flat file database systems' don't generally handle user permisions in a native fashion, it is put onto the interface development to hand this.

I'm not sure how helpful the answer is, but it may take you a little way to a solution (even if you end up going for a server/client dbms system)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lotus for this.   A simple start for you:

1. Create a database with one form and one view
2. On the form add whatever fields you want but also add a computed-when-composed multi-value field of type "Readers" with formula:

   "[Admin]" : @Name( [CANONICALIZE];@userName)
3. With the exception of those with an Admin role (e.g., your wife), the view will display to each user only the records that the user created.  The users will have to create one record per row.

Alternatively you could create an agent in the database that reads the data from an Excel file and builds the documents (records) with the READERS field's value computed as the documents are created.

If that's the route you want to take post a reply here and I'll post some code to (i) prompt a user to select an excel file, (ii) read the excel file data into lotus notes, (iii) implement a READERS field to see that documents are kept confidential between the creator and the Admin role people.

Hope that helps.